# Mapping multiple collections in one entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am quite new to hibernate and programming with databases in general to be honest...
I've tried to save some graph-like structure to database.

Suppose I have Java class like this:

```
public class User {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<User> followers = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<User> friends = new ArrayList<>();
    @Id
    private String name;
    .....
}
```

The problem is I want to save it to PostgeSQL database using Hibernate. However I found it quite nontrivial. The one problem for example is:
Suppose I do:

```
User user1 = new User("user1");
User user2 = new User("user2");
user1.getFollowers().add(user2);
user1.getFriends().add(user2);
```

Now if I do merge on user1 object there will be issue with key uniqueness constraint. I wonder if this is the issue because I misconfigured Hibernate annotations to save my structure or it is entirely wrong approach to represent graph in such a way using Hibernate ? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would go for a generated ID column, and would not use the user's name for that. Put a constraint on that name column in the database rather.

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
@Column
private long id;
```

Otherwise I cannot see anything wrong with your approach. Do you get any exceptions while running your code?

Comment: When I changed ID column and dropped not null constraints for some columns in user_user table it seems to save it without exceptions. However there is still this problem that name is supposed to be unique and  saving the same users (with the same name) again using merge in different session results in creating duplicated rows (with the same name) How should I go about it ?

Comment: You just want a unique key constraint on the name.  You don't want to use it as the primary key, or else you can't change the name for a given entity.

 @Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {
  @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"})})